# How to add cell count in UILabel in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to count cell of UITableView and add it in UILabel.
I need to do it as shown in Image

[image]

As in the Image there is count 1,2,3,4 .Did anybody done this.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The *cell count* is the row index plus one because indexes are zero-based. (`indexPath.row + 1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just set the `UILabel` of the cell, like so:

```
cell.countLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)indexPath.row +1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8.0 in

cell.countLabel.text =[nsstring stringwithformate:@"%d",indexpath.row+1];